# how to setup smoker in grass yard?

Tags: outdoor

I'd like to setup a smoker in my backyard. Its one of the cylindrical fairly inexpensive ones. I'm hesitant to just put it on the grass because i don't want any embers to get on the grass and the yard has a slight grade to it.

I'm looking for a fairly painless solution that still will look decent. I

I've considered just picking up 4 12x12 stones and maybe some gravel to help grade under them. Would that be good enough or would it erode over time?

Comment: That will work fine.  The barrel smokers aren't overly heavy.  I used some of the smaller pavers you can get at any big box store and it looked nice and clean.

Comment: @James thanks, did you put anything under them or straight on the grass?

Comment: I put a little sand down just to make sure it was level, pea gravel works pretty well too.